# Batch file: get file timestamp date only and age in days

Tags: datetime, batch-file

The following few lines output the names of certain files in a folder, a delimiter, and a timestamp.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /one *.txt *.pdf *.doc* *.xls* *.msg 2^>nul'
) do echo %indent%%fileBullet% %%F%delimeter% %%~tF
```

So, produces something like this

```
Response.docx; 02/07/2013 12:13 PM
```

I'd like to remove the time portion of the timestamp (so date only), followed by how many days old the file is. So

```
Response.docx; 02/07/2013; 14
```

I've found some fairly lengthy solutions online that contain a dozen or so lines. Is there a short and sweet approach?

Comment: No, batch does not have a short and sweet native ability to perform date arithmetic. You can include "dozens of lines", or switch to another scripting language that supports date arithmetic, or perhaps a hybrid approach, or find and use a 3rd party tool that supports date arithmentic and have your script call that utility as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something shorter and sweeter.  It's not as short and sweet as you'd like, but at least it's not 12 lines of code.  :)

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /one *.txt *.pdf *.doc* *.xls* *.msg 2^>nul'
) do call :datediff "%indent%%fileBullet% %%F%delimeter%" %%~tF

goto :EOF

:datediff
echo wscript.echo DateDiff^("d", "%2", Date^(^)^)>"%temp%\dd.vbs"
set /P i="%~1 %2%delimeter% "<NUL
cscript /nologo "%temp%\dd.vbs"
del /q "%temp%\dd.vbs"
```